# How to Calculate 3 Month Rolling Average with my current dataset in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to power BI and i require your assistance. I want to create a visualisation showing the average number of tickets from the previous 3 months and compare it with the current month. Is there any easy way to do this?
I have tried many solutions online but it dosen't work. I think it is because my dataset may not suit the solution.

My data:
Tickets | Date 
   1    |  6/30/2019 
   1    |  6/10/2019 
   1    |  7/1/2019 
   0    |  7/2/2019 
   1    |  6/30/2019

There are many more columns and rows. The value of ticket is either 1 or 0 and the date can be repeated. This is the data i received from an API.

[This is what i currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo46f.png)
The data would get bigger and bigger as time goes by.
I would want to add a 3month rolling average line in this current visualization that i have.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to make a visualization using line and column charts where each column will show the total number of tickets per month and there will be a line on the chart which will show the average from the previous 3 months

Comment: So you need a new table with the total tickets per month and a column for the average of the previous months?

Comment: Yes, do you know how i can do that? I also have a filter on my date column.

Comment: I look at it today, go for a run now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

First I created a column FirstDayMonth,this I use to group all data of the same month

```
FirstDayMonth = EOMONTH(Tickets[Date];-1)+1
```

My table looks like:

[image]

Next I create a summarized table grouped by the FirstDayMonth

```
TicketsMonth = SUMMARIZE(Tickets;Tickets[FirstDayMonth];"Amount"; SUM(Tickets[Tickets]))
```

I add a column Ave3PrevMonth

```
Ave3PrevMonth = 
    var totalMonths = YEAR(TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth]) * 12 + MONTH(TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth]) - 3
    var periodStart = DATE(totalMonths/12;MOD(totalMonths;12);1)
    var periodEnd = TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth]
return 
    CALCULATE(SUM(TicketsMonth[Amount]);
        FILTER(TicketsMonth; TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth] >= periodStart && TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth] < periodEnd))/3
```

This is the tricky bit as Power bi is not strong with dates..

*I added an extra column PeriodStart to show the date from where average is taken:*

```
PeriodStart = 
    var totalMonths = YEAR(TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth]) * 12 + MONTH(TicketsMonth[FirstDayMonth]) - 3
return DATE(totalMonths/12;MOD(totalMonths;12);1)
```

End result:
[image]

Comment: Hey Aldert, thanks for your answer. I tried to create a column with the formula which u had provided. I tried both creating a calculated column (by right clicking on the table and create new column) and through the edit query way (by clicking on custom column). However, both ways gave me syntax errors. For the calculated column way, i'm getting " unexpected expression ';' " and expected additional parameters. For the edit query way, i'm getting "Token Comma Expected".

Comment: This is regional setting, you use “,” I use “;”. You need to replace all ;